# Forwarding loopback IP to another IP

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iptables

I have loopback IP `127.0.a.b` and remote (not-public) IP `x.x.x.x`

I need to implement traffic "forwarding" on my ubuntu machine,
such that all traffic that is coming/going to `x.x.x.x:9092` will be redirected to `127.0.a.b:9092`.

Per my understanding doing `nc -zv x.x.x.x 9092` should be successful ( this is how I am going to test forwarding )

I am trying to using iptables to achieve this.
Here is what I tried, but this doesn't work

**./fw_helper.sh x.x.x.x 127.0.a.b 9092**

```
#!/bin/bash
src_ip=$1
dst_ip=$2
port=$3

sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s $src_ip --sport $port -d $dst_ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s $dst_ip --sport $port -d $src_ip --dport $port -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s $src_ip --sport $port --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $dst_ip
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $dst_ip --sport $port --dport $port -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport $port --dport $port -d $dst_ip -s $src_ip -j ACCEPT
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 127.0.a.b configured on lo interface and some software listening on 127.0.a.b:9092.

You need just one rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 9092 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.a.b
```

and

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

If not works add second rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 9092 -j SNAT --to 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: thanks for comment! but I don't see IP redirection from specific IP to another concrete IP in your example. I am missing something?

Comment: Your question formulation is wired. 127.0.0.0/8 are host scoped addresses - they accessible from host itself only. Each host has its own 127.0.0.0/8 subnet. So between what hosts you need forwarding? From what host to what host you want connect to 9092 port? If you need connect to some x.x.x.x:9092 from another host just connect to it

Comment: Your rules are valid for redirect to another host with public or private address but you can't redirect or access 127/8 from another host by definition.

Comment: Agree it's weird. I want to have forwarding enabled in the current host itself were 127.0.a.bs are defined., so traffic ( on that same machine ) that is bound to x.x.x.x:9092 "redirects" to 127.0.a.b:9092

Comment: @libXelar.so try updated answer

Comment: @libXelar.so add `ip addr` and `ss -npl ` output to your question.

Comment: That worked, I needed to add DNAT on OUTPUT chain only in nat table. thanks for hint !

Answer (score 0):

so problems solved with 1 iptables line
`sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.249.68.185 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.14.8`

[image]

Comment: You.may checkout https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg  to better understand packets flow in netfilter